# C#, sp_executesql and Incorrect Syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005, sql-server-profiler

I'm calling the code below.

On the line *(IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())* sql barfs with an *Incorrect syntax near 'CompanyUpdate'.*

```
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CompanyUpdate"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyID",SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description",SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
            cmd.Parameters["@CompanyID"].Value = companyid;
            cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = description;

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=[datasource];Initial Catalog=dotNext;User ID=[user];Password=[password];Pooling=True;Application Name=dotNext");
            cn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    this.CompanyID = dr.GetInt32(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

I had a look at sqlprofiler and noticed the following:

```
exec sp_executesql N'CompanyUpdate',N'@CompanyID int,@Description varchar(50)',@CompanyID=56,@Description='APC'
```

Its wrapping my command wit a sp_executesql.  All my other sql commands are just executed with no issues.

So my question is two fold:
1.  Why is it using sp_executesql?
2.  What am I doing wrong?

Details:  sql2005, c#, vs2005

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I notice that you've not set the CommandType to StoredProcedure... I don't know if that's the cause of your problem or not:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

I've done this so many times myself I can't count.

**Tip to trigger your memory when this throws exceptions next time:**

Have SQL Query Profiler open while you're running your app. When each command executes, it shows the SQL generated and run on the server side. If the SQL generated begins with `sp_executesql` followed by your query then it's being run as a regular query - i.e. `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text`, if it starts with `exec`, chances are it's run as a stored proc. Make sure you're getting the correct SQL generated for the type of query you're trying to run.

Comment: Argh, thanks. Why on earth wouldn't it error out if you add parameters to a SqlCommand and don't set it to StoredProcedure...

Comment: Because you can parameterize queries too, so it's not a requirement that it be a stored procedure in order to be able to add parameters...

Comment: +1 I just did the same stupid thing of forgetting to set that.